# Problema para conectar meu dispositivo ao Android Studio por Wi-Fi

Tags: android, android-studio, debug

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que precisa que a porta USB do dispositivo não esteja conectada, então para não atrapalhar nos testes, preciso conectar o celular no Android Studio através do Wi-Fi, no passado já tinha conseguido fazer essa conexão, mas agora que preciso encontro o seguinte problema [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui].

Ou seja quando eu tento conectar com o *ip* do meu dispositivo ele retorna que não consegue conectar.

Atualizei o Android Studio, as configurações de Wi-Fi no celular já estão com permissões de desenvolvedor e mesmo assim não funciona.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você, sem perceber cometeu um equívoco quando usou a porta `555` quando na verdade seria `5555`.

Para realizar o procedimento corretamente, siga os passos abaixo:

**Passo 1:** Para conectar o dispositivo via wifi, no primeiro instante é necessário que ele esteja conectado ao cabo USB. Então conecte o dispositivo e verifique se a depuração está funcionando.

**Passo 2:** Na linha de comando, insira a porta corretamente usando adb:

```
c:\Users\...># adb tcpip 5555
```

**Passo 3:** Conecte ao dispositivo após a verificação do *ip*:

```
c:\Users\...># adb connect 192.168.15.14:5555
```

**Passo 4:** Desconecte o USB e "*tacale pau nesse carrinho*".

> **IMPORTANTE**: deixar a opção ativada é um tanto quanto perigoso. Qualquer pessoa em sua rede pode se conectar ao seu dispositivo em
>   depuração, mesmo se você estiver na rede de dados. Faça isso somente
>   quando conectado a um Wi-Fi confiável e lembre-se de desconecta-lo
>   quando terminar!

Para mais detalhes e discussões sobre  depuração via USB, veja esse [Post #9](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=7594419&postcount=9)<sup>(en)</sup> de um fórum gringo de desenvolvedores.

Comment: Muito Obrigado! Deu tudo certo!

Comment: Legal cara, depois se quiser validar a resposta, fique a vontade. Abs